# Show that there is no efficient estimator for the variance of a normal distribution using properties of the exponential family

Tags: self-study, inference, estimators, exponential-family, efficiency

I want to prove the statement in the title using the following statement from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Efficient_estimator#Finite-sample_efficiency):

> it was proved that efficient estimation is possible only in an exponential family, and only for the natural parameters of that family.

We know that Normal distribution $\mathcal{N}(\mu,\sigma^2)$ belongs to the exponential family. Also from [Wikipedia table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_family#Table_of_distributions) we have:

> [image]

So natural parameters of the Normal family $\mathcal{N}(\mu,\sigma^2)$ are $\eta_1 = \frac{\mu}{\sigma^2}, \, \eta_2 = -\frac{1}{2 \sigma^2}$ and there must exist efficient estimators for them.

But I see that $\sigma^2$ doesn't coincide with $\eta_1$ or $\eta_2$. **Is this the end of the proof? If no, what should I do next?**

**P.S.** I know that there exist other ways to prove the statement but I want to prove it using the abovementioned general propertiy of the exponential families.

Comment: The concept of ["efficiency"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Efficiency_(statistics)#Efficient_estimators) of an estimator relates to whether its variance attains the [Cramér–Rao bound](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cram%C3%A9r%E2%80%93Rao_bound) (for unbiased estimators).  You might want to start by familiarising yourself with the definintion of efficiency from that material.